# F# variable out of context

Tags: f#

In the following dummy code, if I set a break point at the last line, the variable `x` is not accessible in the debugger with:

> the name x does not exist in the current context.

```
module main = 
    let x = 1
    printfn "%d" x
    1
```

But if I change the last line to `1|>ignore` and set a break point there, I can see `x = 1` in the debugger. How does F determine in the first case `x` is out of scope? Thanks.

Comment: (I think a summary comment is that we still have lots of minor bugs regarding what shows up in the debugger 'locals' window when.)

Comment: @Brian - Are there any plans for implementing F#-specific debugger support? I assume there is not much that can be done if F# relies on default C# behavior (Though I don't find that a big deal in practice)

Comment: We don't have plans to implement our own EE, but there is still tons we could do to improve the debugging experience without an EE(e.g. rough edges with locals windows, breakpoint spans, async debugging, ...) if we find the time.

Comment: @Brian, thanks. I just cannot distinguish bugs from features as a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, the `x` value is compiled as a static field of the `main` module (represented as a class).

I think you should be always able to see it in the watches window if you enter `Foo.main.x` (where `Foo` is the namespace of your file - if you don't provide namespace explicitly, this will be generated from the file name such as `foo.fs` in this case).

Why do you see the variable if you add `ignore`? I'm not entirely sure - it is probably because the F# compiler sets the breakpoint to some place in the same class where `x` is placed (as a field). The lookup done by debugger follows the C# (.NET) rules, so it looks at the compiled code and not at the F# source code (because the F# integration doesn't provide its own resolver).

In general, you can assume that local variables can be viewed if you're inside a function where they are declared. Captured variables in a closure can be *usually* accessed using `this` (which gives you reference to the closure object), but this may depend on some compiler internals.